# specific number of characters string in php

Tags: php, string

I want to generate specific characters string. I need to generate exact 35 characters string for that I am using this function.

```
var_dump(str_pad("some text some text", 35, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT));
```

So, it's giving me this output:

```
string(35) "some text some text "
```

That's exactly fine. It'll add blank spaces for remaining characters.

But, For this type of scenario, I want to discard characters above 35.

```
var_dump(str_pad("some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text", 35, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT));
```

Current Output:

```
string(79) "some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text"
```

I need it 35 characters here as well by discarding last few characters from string.

Comment: `str_pad(substr($str, 0, 35), 35, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `substr` on the initial string to cut it down to 35 characters and *then* padding:

```
$data = "some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text";
$data35 = str_pad(substr($data, 0, 35), 35, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT);

var_dump($data35);
/*
    will output:
    string(35) "some text some text some text some "
*/
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (mb_strlen($string,"UTF-8") > 34){
    //there are 35 or more characters to the string
    $string = mb_substr($string,0,35,"UTF-8");
}
else {
    //there are 34 or less characters so carry on
    $string = str_pad($string, 35, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}
```

Using `mb_substr` to remove the string length exceeding the 35 characters limit. This is the MultiByte variation which I think should be recommended for counting.

Comment: 1) `$string[35]` will raise a notice if it does not exist. 2) Its value will be `null`, not `false`. 3) Using byte offsets (`[35]`) on the one hand and `mb_substr` on the other is bound to fail in certain cases. 4) This could be much simpler.

Comment: cheers @deceze I had considered using `is_null` and then went for the `false` approach. And yes I hadn't considered the byte offset of the array. Updated.

Comment: OK, better. But still, you should either handle strings multi-byte compliant all the way, or not at all. Here you're mixing those two approaches in your two different code paths.

Comment: yeah, I was simply taking the OP code as the `else` . I *think* OP could use `mb_internal_encoding` for the whole document but there's no specific `mb_str_pad` native function but there are various user-made ones. You should put your comment as an answer @deceze .